# Grounding a branch circuit with EGC attached to a different panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm trying to add an equipment ground to an old branch circuit, and I had an idea about how to do it in a slightly non-standard way, but I'm not sure if it's safe. I drew a diagram to explain my situation:

[image]

The ungrounded circuit originates from my main panel, and it's going to be quite difficult to run new EGC all the way to it. However, I have a subpanel which is much newer, and for which all the attached branch circuits *do* have EGCs. The grounded receptacles on this newer, grounded branch circuit happen to be physically very close to the receptacles I'm trying to ground on the older branch circuit. In the subpanel, the neutral and ground bus bars are separate, and in the main panel they are combined.

What I would like to do is shown in this second diagram:

[image]

I would like to make a connection between the EGC of the newer branch circuit and the ground ports of my receptacles on the older branch. In the event of a ground fault on the older branch, there would be a low-resistance path back through the ground bus bar of the subpanel, to the ground/neutral bus bar in the main panel. I feel like this would achieve the purpose of the EGC.

Here's why I'm unsure...I have heard in the past a comment along the lines of "you should ground receptacles with EGC running directly back to the panel from which the branch originates." So, this would violate that principle, in "stealing" the EGC from the subpanel, when the branch originates on the main panel.

Can someone tell me if it's okay to do what I have proposed, and if not, help me understand why not?

EDIT: Here is my summary of the discussion: this proposal is technically not compliant with the NEC, specifically section 250.130(C). It is *still* a mystery what adverse scenario the drafters had in mind when they left out this type of fix from the list of specifically allowed fixes. It appears that it would have to involve significant reconfiguration of the home's wiring system, like complete removal or replacement of one of the subpanels (which in my case at least seems unlikely in the future). It's solidly in a gray area where this fix is basically "fine and functional under the vast majority of operating conditions, but technically-speaking not code-compliant as of Mar 2024"

Comment: The subpanel grounding is through the main panel right?  It's in the same building, it doesn't have its own grounding?

Comment: That is correct, subpanel is in the basement of the same building. Grounding electrodes (2 of them) are attached to the shared neutral-ground bus bar in the main panel. Ground bus bar in the subpanel does not have it's own grounding electrodes, it is just connected directly to bus in the main panel.

Comment: You have an option to install a GFCI outlet without an equipment ground.  Is there a specific reason you want an equipment ground?  Is it for a device that requires one?  If so, another option is to install a GFCI outlet (for safety) and a separate equipment ground serving the needs of your equipment but not subject to NEC safety requirements.

Comment: The reason I want an equipment ground is two-fold:

1. I *do* want to have it available for sensitive equipment that requires it.
2. If I ever resell the property, an inspector's receptacle tester is going to show an ungrounded outlet with anything other than an equipment ground (including the GFCI solution). I realize this would be code-compliant, but I don't want to have to argue with the buyer about why this is still safe. Some buyers hear "ungrounded" and immediately run for the hills because they won't take the time to understand ground faults and how GFCI is a fine solution.

Comment: Well, if you do what you drew you'll make buyers and inspectors happy and your transgression will be mainly metaphysical.   Between you and the Gods of Code.  It would be a good idea to understand the "why" question before electing to go that way, but at least on the day you install it your ground path will be real.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback jay, gives me some things to think about :) I wonder if this is the kind of thing that might change in the NEC at some point down the line. Being a first-time DIYer I haven't really looked at code before and don't have a good sense for how often in changes.

Comment: If you put in a GFCI outlet and connect its ground via the wrong panel you can omit the "No equipment ground" sticker, your $5 tester will be happy, and you will not be relying on the non-compliant ground path to protect users.    A failure in your provided equipment ground path will not cause the GFCI to stop working.    I *still* don't know if that's code-compliant, but you do seem to have your cake and eat it.

Answer (score 6):

[NEC 250.130(C)](https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#250.130_(C)) specifies allowed connection points, your proposal is not included. Basically you can attach upstream but not down another path.

Comment: Can you help me understand why this part of the code does not allow for grounding conductor from a different enclosure? What is the fault scenario that the code is trying to avoid? Also, it sounds like there might be a different answer depending on whether the subpanel has its own dedicated grounding electrodes?

Comment: It's hard to know the reasons for every bit of code, and sometimes it is because certain configurations have been proven to be safe while others simply have not been proven to be safe, even if they are.   You can imagine scenarios where the low-resistance path between a branch circuit and its grounding electrodes become severed over time, and borrowed grounds from the same panel aren't subject to that danger.  It does seem very unlikely.  But 250.130(C)(4) seems quite specific about the two branch circuits needing to be from the same enclosure.  "Why" is a good question.

Comment: Why would the borrowed grounds from the same panel not be subject to the same danger?

Comment: The more I think about it, the less I understand this.  No matter what bizarre scenario I dream up where the subpanel becomes somehow divorced from the rest of the building's electrical system, you *still* have all the grounds bonded together.  You'd have to be purposeful to remove all ground current paths from your new outlet to the main breaker ground bus.  Like, your subpanel would have to become a totally separate system fed by a separate service drop with its own ground rods and intentionally not bonded to the first one.  This answer remains correct, "why" is a great question.

Comment: Here is a stretched scenario: The subpanel feed including the ground wire from the main panel is all disconnected for some construction or maintenance.  *Simultaneously* your guitar amp (or whatever) experiences a live-to-chassis fault.  Now your entire subpanel and everything connected to it is on an energized ground island.  Like I said above .... this is super-stretched and the benefits of having a grounded outlet seem to outweigh it.

Comment: Another scenario: power and ground are connected to different subpanels. At some later date, one of the subpanels is moved to a different main panel. Now the neutral and ground are no longer bonded for that outlet.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau the new main panel and the old one, *although in the same building* would have to not be properly bonded by any means.  It seems unlikely in a residence.  The new panel would likely be right next to the old one.  Your scenario is not impossible, I'm just struggling to understand how your scenario (or mine) makes OP's plan unwise.